# Emphasis in comments is no longer italic

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

With the recent style upgrade, `*...*` emphasis (italics) in comments are now broken:

[image]

[image]

The HTML is fine:

```
and so on are ultimately different <i>input</i> scenarios; 
catching all of them in a plain <snip> is a fruitless endeavour. 
(Damn, I <i>do</i> need to write that book!)</span>
```

Comment: `Does it *also* happen on Meta?` Does it *also* happen on Meta?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this.

Comment: No-repro. I see the emphasized words in italic in [this comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/77865/onnm-onm-omnm#comment166610_77865).

Comment: Huh. FF 52, Ubuntu 16.04. I *see* `font-style: italic;` in the Inspector. A font issue?

Comment: Persists in FF 55. I'd be grateful for any hints! FWIW, Open Sans is installed on my system, including the italic variant. A small test HTML using the same font displays as expected.

Comment: Can no longer reproduce in FF56.

Comment: Still fine with the new design beta and FF 62.