# Why are bold and italics disabled on CS.SE?

Tags: bug, design, formatting

**This sentence is bold.** *And this sentence is in italics.*

Or at least they're supposed to be. Why are they not rendered as such?

Comment: I confirm, both under Chrome and under Firefox, both here and on the main site, on Linux. But it's working on other Stack Exchange sites and under Windows. So it must be a bug in the CSS or in the font choices for this site.

Comment: [Interesting](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1402/98). Same here.

Comment: It fails in Firefox on Unix, works on Windows and iOS. *Test in comment* <- should be italics.

Comment: Oh I forgot to add, it fails for me on Windows 7 using Firefox.

Comment: @Raphael This time it's probably due to [styling changes to prepare for responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305560/2018-monthly-product-team-updates) (yay!). Looks like a bug snuck in.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with Chrome 64 on Win 10. The offending `font-family` is "Open Sans", and the version of Open Sans installed in Windows seems to support bold and italics fine.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Oh hey there :)

Comment: This may be [part of a problem that affects other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307120/i-cannot-get-bold-or-italics-to-work).

Comment: I for one can't reproduce these issues anymore (new beta theme, FF 62). You?